# Why is function() {...} needed to invoke a function after an onclick event?

Tags: javascript

Why is it necessary to include **function()** here in JavaScript?

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = function() { myFunction(); };
```

Why does just putting the function you wish to invoke not work?

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction();
```

Comment: It works if you stop calling the function in the last one and just reference the function instead. In other words, remove the parenthesis from the last line.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if I wanted to pass certain arguments to the function? I wouldn't be able to do this without the parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, in this case yo use the first option of defining a new, unnamed function that invokes your actual handler with the parameters.

Comment: @CamarelliniViberg If you need params, then you need first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assignment

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction();
```

you assign to the left side the **result** of calling `myFunction()`, not the function object. Say, if `myFunction()` returns `'Hello'`, then the assignment is equivalent to

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = 'Hello';
```

which is not what you want. In contrast, `function () {...}` is a code snippet that is assigned to the `onclick` and will be called when the event occurs.

Note that you can use parameters inside `function () {...}`:

```
... = function () { return myFunction ('Hello', 1, x, y); }
```

where x and y are variables visible in the scope where this definition occurs.

If you don't need any parameters, then you can instead simply do this:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction;
```

given that `myFunction` is a pointer to the corresponding code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

The onclick handler needs a function to call (e.g. `myFunction`), not the *result* of a function call (e.g. `myFunction()`). So try this:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction;
```

Essentially the onclick setter is expecting an executable function. By writing `myFunction()`, you are asking for `myFunction` to be called before the onclick setter is invoked. Instead, you want to pass (a reference to) `myFunction`, so that the event handler can call it later.

---Edit: Less common ---

As @Zeta suggests, what is important is the thing that is passed to the setter, not whether it came from a function. So it is entirely possible to do this:

```
function myFunctionMaker() {
    return function() { ... };
}
blah.onclick = myFunctionMaker();
```

Here, myFunctionMaker is returning a function, so the result is actually executable. This is not a common thing to do, so if that doesn't make sense, stick with the first option of just passing the function.

Comment: Nitpicking, but the result of a function call can be a function.

Comment: @Zeta: fair enough, elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

The `.onlick` attribute needs an *event handler*, which is simply a *function* in this context. Now lets have a look at the types on your right hand side, assuming that `myFunction` doesn't return anything (and therefore `undefined`):

```
typeof function() { myFunction(); } === "function"
typeof myFunction()                 === "undefined"
```

And as you can see, invoking `myFunction` doesn't give you a function at all, so it's not compatible to the onclick attribute. Keep in mind that obviously

```
typeof myFunction                   === "function"
```

and your first line of code could be simplified to

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

`function() { myFunction(); };`

is a function *expression* whereas

`myFunction();`

is a function call. When you do the latter, you're just calling the function and the result gets placed into `onclick`. In the first case, you're actually giving a function, that's why you need the former notation.

Giving the function name without the parenthesis, will also work properly, like:

`document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = myFunction;`

since `myFunction` here is an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a function name followed by parentheses '()' is an invokation, while the name itself represents only a reference to that function (which you want to assign to a handler like .onclick).