# What does mean that a function returns functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Below I have a simple code, that prints out a list of 3 s, each containing a memo of thing to do, on the right of each todo there's a button to delete the todo.

```
<body>
    
    <div id="todo-list"></div>

    <script>

      let todos = [{
          title: 'Get groceries',
          id: 'id1',
        }, {
          title: 'Wash car',
          id: 'id2',
        }, {
          title: 'Make dinner',
          id: 'id3',
      }];

      const onDelete = todoToDelete => {
        return () => {
          removeTodo(todoToDelete.id);
          
          render();
        };
      }

      const removeTodo = idToDelete => {
        todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== idToDelete);

      }


      function render() {
        document.getElementById('todo-list').innerHTML = '';

        todos.forEach(function (todo) {
          const element = document.createElement('div');
          element.innerText = todo.title;

          const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
          deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
          deleteButton.onclick = onDelete(todo);
          element.appendChild(deleteButton);

          const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
          todoList.appendChild(element);
        });
      }

      render();
    </script>
  </body>
```

I don't really understand the meaning of return () => in the onDelete, it has something that has to do with the closure?
Can I write a single function that combines onDelete and removeTodo functions?

Comment: You do not want to execute the right way instead of assigning it to onClick. When you click on the button via dom then it should execute onDelete(), You can try to remove that `() =>`. You will notice that it will run that function immediately

Comment: yes you can: https://jsfiddle.net/43zbpg2o/

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at this line:

```
deleteButton.onclick = onDelete(todo);
```

An event handler requires a function to work. `onDelete` is called with the current `todo` object as an argument. `onDelete` then returns a *new* function, and that is the function that is assigned to the handler.

And because that returned function is a closure it maintains a reference to that todo object. It passes that on to `removeTodo` as an argument when it is called, and `removeTodo` uses the value of that object's id in its filtering process.

If you wanted to combine the two functions you can.

```
const onDelete = todoToDelete => {
  return () => {
    todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== todoToDelete.id);
    render();
  );
};
```

Comment: Can I think of the event handler in this situation needs a function to be returned, as if it needs to know the entire code that the function removeTodo does? Otherwise the event handler hasn't the full controll of the function removeTodo, and could not pass an argument to it?

Comment: I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735726/why-is-function-needed-to-invoke-a-function-after-an-onclick-event